# Embedding Facebook Posts Responsive

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

Facebook claims its embedded posts are adjusted automatically based on the screen sizes.

Please see **Can I customize the width of Embedded Posts?** section in the below link.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts

However, the embed doesn't seem to be responsive. Please see my test here,

http://colombowebs.com/test/fb/

Is there anything I have to do in addition to make it responsive?

Comment: If it say that it is but it isn't that is a bug and you should file one at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs . But reading the text it say it will be the size of the container on mobile and on desktop you have to specify width

Answer (score 1):

You have to use javascript/jquery to obtain the desired result. I have taken help from [responsive function](http://jsfiddle.net/brohde/GRcen/) and created the following which works almost for all widths.

```
(function ($) {

    jQuery.fn.autoResizeFbPost = function () {

        var fixWidth = function ($container, $clonedContainer, doParse) {
            // default parameter. 
            doParse = typeof doParse == 'undefined' ? true : doParse;
            var updatedWidth = $container.width();
            // update all div.fb-post with correct width of container
            var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 600px)");

            if (isMobile.matches) {
                //Conditional script here  
                if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
                    // you're in PORTRAIT mode
                    updatedWidth = $(window).width();
                }

                if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
                    // you're in LANDSCAPE mode
                    updatedWidth = $(window).height();
                }
            }

            $clonedContainer
                .find('div.fb-post')
                .each(function () {
                    $(this).attr('data-width', updatedWidth);
                });
            $('div.embedded', $clonedContainer).each(function () {
                $(this).attr('max-width', updatedWidth);
            });
            // update page with adjusted markup
            $container.html($clonedContainer.html());

            //should we call FB.XFBML.parse? we don't want to do this at page load because it will happen automatically
            if (doParse && FB && FB.XFBML && FB.XFBML.parse)
                FB.XFBML.parse();
        };

        return this.each(function () {

            var $container = $(this),
             $clonedContainer = $container.clone();

            // make sure there is a .fb-post element before we do anything.
            if (!$container.find('div.fb-post').length) {
                return false;
            }

            // execute once (document.ready) and do not call FB.XFBML.parse()
            fixWidth($container, $clonedContainer, false);

            $(window).bind('resize', function () {
                fixWidth($container, $clonedContainer);
            }).trigger('resize');
       });
    };

})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#post').autoResizeFbPost();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And your HTML should be like

```
<div style="background-color: white;" id="post">
  <div class="fb-post" data-href="your-facebook-post-url" mobile="false"></div>
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free to post your comments.